# Designing a networking layer in Android app

Tags: android

I am working on an android app with some networking aspects. There are places in the app that, when a button is pressed, a call is made to a server with a response full of data coming back. My question is regarding creating a robust flow where i have my network calls separated in their own class and all i do is instantiate a networking object such as new MyNetworkHelper(accessClientServer) and give it the name of a client server. This object would then instantiate the appropriate object (ClientServer or StudentServer or TeacherSever etc) to do with accessing that server and doing any database saving and returning a response to the MyNetworkHelper object which would return to the button that was pressed.

Is this the best way to do this kind of task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose is not unreasonable but could be more standardized using standard patterns such as your helper being a Singleton (and your additional servers as well if they are intended to be used in such a fashion). I would recommend you pick up a beginner book in Design Patterns and Architecture.

Comment: I would recommend this book as a quick starter book with learning by example... http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Object-Oriented-Analysis-Design/dp/0596008678/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1369022967&sr=8-1&keywords=ooa%26d